# How to use the app object in cloud functions without passing it as parameter?

Tags: firebase

I am building cloud functions for the backend of my app but I couldn't figure out a way to use the app or db variables without passing them into my functions as parameters. I tried initializing the apps seperately in its own functions but multiple app initialization of the same app is not allowed but I want to use only one app.
So the question is, is there a way to implement the below code without passing the app/db parameter into every function?
**PS**: Also I would appreciate if you could suggest few tips to improve the quality of the file structuring and how I import / export functions.

**index.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const cors = require("cors")({ credentials: true, origin: true });


const app = admin.initializeApp();
const db = app.firestore();


const { addVehicle } = require("./src/vehicles/addVehicle");
const { getVehicles } = require("./src/vehicles/getVehicles");

exports.addVehicle = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    const result = await addVehicle(req, res, db);
    res.json((result));
  });
});


exports.getVehicles = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  
  cors(req, res, async () => {
    res.json((await getVehicles(req,res,db)));
  });
});
```

**addVehicle.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const Vehicle = require("../../models/Vehicle");




exports.addVehicle = async (req, res, db) => {
  try{
    const vehicleInfo = new Vehicle(req.body);

    const addedVehicle = await db.collection("vehicles").add(vehicleInfo);
    console.log(addedVehicle);

    res.json({data: "Succesfully added vehicle"});
  }
  catch(err){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
  }
};
```

**getVehicles.js**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const Vehicle = require("../../models/Vehicle");




exports.getVehicles = async (req, res, db) => {
  try{
    const vehiclesSnapshot = await db.collection("vehicles").get();
    
    const vehicles = [];
    vehiclesSnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      vehicles.push(doc.data());
      
    });

    res.json({ data: vehicles });
  }
  catch(err){
    if(err){
      res.json(err);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: I would rather avoid to use global variables. The reasons are different, but one of the best effects of passing the variables as parameters is that you implement an inversion of control. This way, you could use a dependency injection library and the single functions are way more testable.

Comment: @GregorioPalamà thank you very much for the comment, so you say that this way is just fine right?